# Форма записи функциональным методов массивов вместе со стрелочными функциями

Tags: javascript, функции, функциональное-программирование

Интересует какая форма записи стрелочных функций, из приведенных ниже, наиболее оптимальна с точки зрения понимания и читаемости кода, и с точки зрения лаконичности записи кода. Так сказать, к чему себя приучать с самого начала изучения JS. Я уже привык писать как в v 2, но встретил вариант записи v 4, которая, кажется, лучше для понимания. Дайте совет, пожалуйста.

```
/ v 1
 const getUsersByEyeColor = (arr, color) => 
  arr.filter(val => val.eyeColor === color);

// v 2
 const getUsersByEyeColor = (arr, color) => arr.filter(
   val => val.eyeColor === color
  );

// v 3
const getUsersByEyeColor = (arr, color) => {
  return arr.filter(val => val.eyeColor === color);
};

// v 4
const getUsersByEyeColor = (arr, color) => {
  const usersByEyeColor = arr.filter(user => user.eyeColor === color);
  return usersByEyeColor;
};

console.log(getUsersByEyeColor(users, 'blue')); 




const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    phone: '+1 (848) 556-2344',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  }, 
  ....
]
```

Comment: чем первый от второго варианта отличается, а третий от четвергото?

Comment: В первом и втором минимальные различия. В четвертом в теле функции создается функция с названием, в которую передается параметр с названием user, что как бы лучше воспринимается чем просто el (как в предыдущих трех). Вопрос, может, странный, но хочется, что используется на ваших проектах. До этого никогда не сталкивался с программированием.

Comment: Вообще все примеры плохие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все примеры выглядят не очень: с одной стороны название переменной `getUsersByEyeColor`, с другой во всех вариантах параметр называется `arr`.

Чтобы сделать более читабельно, стоит просто поменять имена параметров, например:

```
const getUsersByEyeColor = (users, color) => users.filter(user => user.eyeColor === color);
```

Тогда и смысл в промежуточной переменной, как в четвертом варианте отпадает, и сразу видно, что принимаются юзеры, и проверяется конкретный юзер.